# How to import excel in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to import a excel sheet (csv or xlsx) on PHP with Laravel framework, and I need to know how is the best way to do it.

Comment: What have you tried? Is there a specific library you’re using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use https://github.com/box/spout or https://github.com/maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel

Spout is faster, but Laravel-Excel has more features.

Import Example:

```
use Box\Spout\Reader\Common\Creator\ReaderEntityFactory;
$reader = ReaderEntityFactory::createReaderFromFile('/path/to/file.ext');
$reader->open($filePath);
foreach ($reader->getSheetIterator() as $sheet) {
    foreach ($sheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
        // do stuff with the row
        $cells = $row->getCells();
    }
}
$reader->close();
```

And in Laravel-Excel you can import directly to a model:

```
(new UsersImport)->import('users.xlsx', null, \Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::XLSX);
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you much.